# Linode + MongoHQ, or host my own DB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, hosting, linode, mongohq

Am working on a project using python/flask/mongodb, and needed to figure out the hosting/infrastructure.

Prefer to use VPS'es instead of services like Heroku.

Which in your opinion is the better option ?
a) Linode app/web server + mongoHQ
b) Linode app/web server + mongodb & replicas setup on a few Linodes
c) AWS EC2 with MongoHQ (sicne mongohq is hosted on EC2 as well)
d) Any other advisable suggestions?

I am experienced in Linux/DB in general, hence more concerned about the maintenance efforts, distracting me from delivering actual application features.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up trying the Linode + MongoHQ combo? Was the latency acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question to answer as there's no correct answer to this.

This all depends on your traffic, application uptime needs and ultimately your manpower and infrastructure.

If you're a one person startup and with limited Mongo DB knowledge (ie setting up replicasets, sharding etc) then go with Mongo HQ.  I have done some test instances with Heroku as the app layer and they work well enough.

As you grow it might be a good idea to hire a dedicated mongo person and/or sign up for paid 10gen support which also gives you access to their monitoring console and other goodies to help management.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be to watch your queries... When generating search result pages, specify only the fields you want and need from the db... Your throughout and latency aye generally a bigger cost for queries from remote systems than execution time for a query.

Also see if MongoLab or MongoHQ have in site or hosting from a priority connection to your vps site of choice.

Having managed db hosting can be a really nice thing.